# Azure vpn is establish but causing delay or no traffic sometimes

Tags: networking, azure, ubuntu-14.04, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn

We are trying to establish VPN  Hillstone FW (device) with Azure.
VPN details are:

```
VPN type: Policy based
Gateway Subnet: 192.168.50.10/29
default subnet: 192.168.50.0/29 
VM inet Address: 192.168.50.4
and Other side
Device  : Hillstone FW
server 1:10.215.369.5/32
server 2:10.215.369.10/32
server 3:10.215.369.11/32
server 4:202.89.35.48/32
```

We have add all these in local network gateway as it is.
On device side they allowed/routed only VM(debian ubuntu) address (192.168.50.4/32) All configurations looking good. For testing,we have open all ports from both ends. As Hillstone FW is not is Azure device compatible list.

But Now VPN is established, On azure portal it showing data in/out. but connection status is flapping from connected to connecting...

They didn't allow reverse ping. When we ping/telent from Vm it happens only 50%, sometimes it gives reply and more times not. and mostly ping packets are dropped upto 60%.
Should we asked them to allow entire subnet 192.168.50.0/29?
how can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Connection issues in VPN gateways in Azure are generally related to key refresh times and who initiates the refresh.  It is always best to allow Azure to initiate the refresh as required.

Ensure that you are meeting the parameters shown on [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices/#ipsec-parameters)